# Different IP while making two requets throught UrlFetchApp in same script

Tags: google-apps-script

Can we relly that while Google App Script is executed by a Time Trigger, and makes two subsequest request using UrlFetchApp, both are made by same server with the same IP?

I need to ensure it, because in one request I query for an Access token for a remote service and with another I'm using this Access token. The remote service that I'm quering checks if the Access token was requested by the client with the same IP as requests that use this Access Token.

**EDIT**

I examined the behavior by time-triggering some dumb scripts with just few consecutive UrlFetchApp requests in them and checked server logs. I had two clear observations:

1. IP may vary in consecutive calls within one trigger
2. There is  clear rotation of the IPs, sometimes there is a group of 7 consecutive calls with the same IP, sometimes 6. But in general there are always groups.

Because I wanted to only use Google infrastructure for my script and occasional failure was not a problem, I came up with a ugly ugly but working solution:

```
function batchRequest(userLogin, userPassword, webapiKey, resource, attributes, values ){
  var token = requestToken(userLogin, userPassword, webapiKey ); // requestToken method uses UrlFetchApp.fetch
  var result = request(resource, token,  attributes, values); // requestToken method uses UrlFetchApp.fetch with options.muteHttpExceptions set to true so that we can read the response code

  var i = 0;
  while (result.getResponseCode() == 500 && i < 10){
    token = requestToken(userLogin, userPassword, webapiKey ); // requestToken method uses UrlFetchApp.fetch
    result = request(resource, token,  attributes, values);
    i++;
  }
  return result;
}
```

So I simply try hard max 10 times and hope to hook up to have the two requests — one for token and another for some bussiness logic — done in a same ‘IP group’.

I put more detailed description here: https://medium.com/p/dd0746642d7

Answer (score 0):

Within the same trigger call yes. From another trigger no. Based on experience nce but i havent seen this docummented.

Comment: I observe diffrent behaviour -> once I execute the script from within the script editor it indeed uses the same IP for both requests, but once the execution is time triggered it behaves upredictable and sometimes uses same sometime not. And it's bad for my stuff. Any one know any workaround to ensure the same server make two subsequent fetches?

Comment: you mean inside the same trigger call the ip changes when you do two consecutive calls to urlFetch?

Comment: yes - the IP of a server that actually performs the request. I suppose Google queues that . But I observe this bevahiour SOMETIMES and only when the execution of a script is trigger by a time trigger. But anyway this SOMETIMES makes huge difference because I can't relly on it.

Comment: Difference might be related to caching, i believe urlFetch from a trigger has a different default so try hardcoding caching options. Are both urls identical?

Comment: I tried with catching but it was nothing to do with it - but thanks anyway for the suggestion. I decided to examine the behaviour and I documented it here: https://medium.com/p/dd0746642d7

Comment: how did you try with caching? also, try comparing if this returns a different object on each call:  response = UrlFetchApp.getRequest(..)